# How can I determine which command / step failed within a travis build

Tags: travis-ci

So I have a CICD travis build that failed... How do I know which line / step is the culprit?

Comment: Have you looked at the output of the build that failed?

Comment: Please improve your question to include relevant output of your failed build.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Travis CI Logs.  Often a failed build step will return "Error", "Failure", "-1", buried in a wall of text.  If you want a better way to collect and  these logs you can check out the following:

- [Official Github page with details on how log collection works](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-logs)
- [An official blog on how to structure your production logs.](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-04-11-fun-with-logs/)

Comment: So manually search / grep for "Exited with 1" / "Error"?